# What does jQuery's removeClass method return?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused about these lines of JQuery:

```
if ($(ui).hasClass("color1"))
    $(ui).removeClass("color1").addClass("color2")
else
    $(ui).removeClass("color2").addClass("color1")
```

in [this code](http://componentjs.com/tutorial.html#step4-app-d2-js).

I know that `$(ui)` is creating a JQuery instance. I would like to know if
`.hasClass` is testing the entire DOM tree of the JQuery instance for
any element which has `color1` as part of its class attributes.

Also, [the docs for
removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) do not state what
`removeClass` returns. They do so allegorically with this code:

```
$("p").removeClass("myClass noClass").addClass("yourClass");
```

But I would prefer an explicit statement about what `removeClass()`
returns. Because my second questions is: what is returned by removeClass and how is addClass can making use of it?

Comment: It returns the selected element(s) wrapped in a jQuery object, just like all other jquery setter methods.

Comment: The essence of all jQuery chaining!

Comment: `Returns: jQuery` from the docs is pretty clear in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns the `jQuery` object. See the documentation of the `removeClass` function: http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

And the `jQuery` object: http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery

Excerpt from the documentation of the `jQuery` object:

> A jQuery object contains a collection of Document Object Model (DOM)
>   elements that have been created from an HTML string or selected from a
>   document. Since jQuery methods often use CSS selectors to match
>   elements from a document, the set of elements in a jQuery object is
>   often called a set of "matched elements" or "selected elements".

Answer (score 2):

It returns the elements you selected using the query:

```
$("[some query here]").removeClass("...").text("the text that must be set");
```

So, adding `class1` and removing `class2` can be done like bellow:

```
$("query .class2")
    .removeClass("class2")
    .addClass("class1");
```

On the [documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) you can see: **Returns: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)**.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [documentation for removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), it tells you *Returns: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)*

---

[image]